# PHP script in a sub-directory automatically requests an identical script in the root directory when called

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, http

I wanted to migrate some `MySQL` code to `MySQLi`, so I created a sub-directory and copied all the web files into that sub-directory to enable working online while the website continued working without any disturbance and most especially so I could just use the original database configs on the same database. I planned on moving the sub-deirectory to the main directory once the migration was complete.

My major problem now is that when I call `domain.com/subdirectory/script.php`, then end result is that `domain.com/script.php` gets called instead. I have directives in my `.htaccess` that "hides" the `.php` extension so normally the first response is a `302` then a `200`. But now its actually returning a 302 but this time the `location` becomes the script in the main directory even though it was called from the sub-directory.

This is the .htaccess of both the main directory and sub-directory in question:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 domain.com/page-not-found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't check the validity or logic of your rewrite rules. But from what you have asked, I think what you are missing is the [RewriteBase](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive.

> The RewriteBase directive specifies the URL prefix to be used for
>   per-directory (htaccess) RewriteRule directives that substitute a
>   relative path.

You can modify your .htaccess files like this.

You main directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,END]
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 domain.com/page-not-found
```

Your subdirectory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,END]
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 domain.com/page-not-found
```

Here, the only difference is that I added `RewriteBase` and changed the absolute path in redirect location. (`$1` instead of `/$1`)

I hope it helps. Feel free to ask if you have any doubts :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. The problem still persists even after the suggested changes. It is actually a signin script which goes to an account page. Except it goes to the account page in the root directory instead of the subdirectory.

Comment: @RichardNwachukwu can you please share the new .htaccess files of both directories after the change?

Comment: On mobile now. But I copied and pasted exactly your suggestions. The only difference was that I left the redirect location as is, since it was displaying blank pages and only worked when I added .php to the end of the address. Other than that everything is exactly the same

Comment: what do you meant by "I left the redirect location as is" ? Please post when you are back in your pc :) no hurry. [If you use the rewrite base, then all redirections will happen relative to that path, so possibly you cannot leave the location as is]

Comment: Apache version 2.4.18

Comment: @RichardNwachukwu it's really strange. The httaccess file I gave works as expected for me under same apache version (of course without the slash in front of $1 because with that, it won't work.) Can you remove the slash again and try? If it doesn't work, please post your virtualhost config file.

Comment: Perhaps you are calling the file in a wrong location. Try to type in the exact URLs in browser and see if they work. ( I mean without following the flow of your application like login etc. Just try to access the url from the address bar)

Comment: Accessing the url directly works. For instance even after the redirect to dashboard.php instead of sub-directory/dashboard.php, typing sub-directory/dashboard.php works. But immediately I click say the logout.php which is relative to sub-directory/dashboard.php, it ends up calling the main logout.php

Comment: Probably you are linking to logout.php file with the absolute path, i.e like /logout.php? Cannot say much about them because I don't about those files. However if the redirect works, I think I have answered your main question (redirect inside the sub directory and main directory) Your current problem is probably coming from how the files are linked.

Comment: I've tested both relative and absolute paths ie signin.php and domain.com/sub-directory/signin.php both eventually redirect to the main directory's signin.php. This goes for every other script

Comment: I'm sorry, I think this is all I could do :) Without knowing how others scripts really behave, I cannot think of any other solution. This redirection is working perfectly for me. By the way, change that /$1 to $1. That's the issue you have, but you haven't changed it. So I don't know how it would work if you don't change it.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your time and assistance. I would upvote the answer if I could but my reputation is not up to that level yet. I'm very grateful, thanks.

Comment: Everything works well now. $1, $1.php and the RewriteBase were the problem just like you suggested hours ago. I finally took everything piece by piece and now Its working like it should. Thank you very much

Comment: Accepted answer, however cant remove upvote. I need 125 rep for that lol. But thanks for your help